# Can I provide any kind of "hint" for change AD domain password procedure?

Tags: windows, active-directory, password

We are changing password policy in company.

I would like to provide some kind of "company password policy rules" hint to user when user is changing his password using CTRL+ALT+DEL on Windows machine. Default `Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain` is non-desriptive and I would like to replace it with something like `... must be at least ... characters long and must contain ...`, or, maybe add any kind of `help` button or some text.

Is there any **native** way of doing this without third-party software and without patching system files?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no native way of doing so documented, so I am sure there is none.
For a native way, you would need to use a script that users may trigger to change their own pw, that will display all requirements.